# repeated measures vs time series

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures

What is the difference between a time series design and a repeated measures design?

Is it correct to say time series is a kind of repeated measures design?

Comment: I don't know of any such connection. A time series is a sequence of observations in time that are correlated.while a repeated measures design is one where there are subjects that you take observations more than once.  The fact that they are repeated at different time points is usually not an issue. The only design issue I can think of with time series is the time interval for sampling.  Usually the data is taken over equally spaced issues.  What I think you are probably thinking of is what is called longitudinal data or panel data.  It consist of a series of time dependent observations.

Comment: The time dependent observations are associated with a particular subject and they are repeated. a few times.  It is also referred to as panel data. This type of data can be considered as a special form of repeated measures.   Sometimes people say that a time series is a long sequence of correlated observations while longitudinal data is several short series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. But I think I still have some difficulties understanding the difference... I know that a repeated measures design is the one where conditions (or treatments or dependant variable) can be time or whatever. And I know that time series design is the one where we a sample is observed (or measured) over time (equally spaced time)... My problems is that we can consider the Condition (or treatment) as Time in a repeated measures study, and if the time intervals are equal, then can it be a times series study as well?

Comment: Assume that we have three samples of which we have measured their blood pressure at time 0, then after 2 days we measure their blood pressure again, then again after another 2 days... What design is it? If the time intervals were not equal, we knew it would be a repeated measures design. But now in this example what do you think about the design?

Comment: Time series can be applied with unequal time intervals .  It is a more difficult problem.  What distinguishes time series from repeated measures is a single realization.  Time series are not special cases of repeated measures design.  What I said was that you should look into the relationship between longitudinal/panel data analysis and and repeated measures.  You can look at a wikipedia article on longitudinal data and see what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interrupted time series design includes at least three measurements before and at least three measurements after an intervention ([See definition from Cochrane](http://childhoodcancer.cochrane.org/non-randomised-controlled-study-nrs-designs)). Otherwise, it is considered a before and after study ([See AHRQ taxonomy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK95280/)). A before and after study (also known as pre-post study) is "a simple example of repeated measures" [(Study Designs and Their Outcomes, pg. 111)](http://samples.jbpub.com/9780763789961/89961_CH03_Macha.pdf). It is also the case that "Time  series designs can be repeated-measures designs" [(pg. 110)](http://samples.jbpub.com/9780763789961/89961_CH03_Macha.pdf), so it seems reasonable to think of a time series study as a type of repeated measures design.
Cochrane groups time series and repeated-measures studies together in its [good practice data extraction form](http://epoc.cochrane.org/resources/epoc-resources-review-authors), meaning the two study types have the same structure for data extraction purposes, and here is another [published example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4553062/) that refers to time-series studies as a repeated measures design. While time series and repeated measures designs may overlap, the most common example of a 'repeated measures design' seems to be one in which all subjects receive multiple interventions and serve as their own controls (without three measurements before and after the intervention(s). Another characteristic of time series studies, according to the [AHRQ taxonomy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK95280/), is that "The investigator(s) does not assign or have control over the intervention/exposure."